# merge 2 tables on id

Tags: sql

I've 2 tables - TABLE1 & TABLE2

```
TABLE1
city    district    state   nation
1       27          37      41
3       27          37      41
6       29          32      43

TABLE2
id  name
1   c1
3   c2
6   c3
27  d1
29  d2
32  s1
37  s2
41  n1
43  n2
```

and I need output like below. ie, corresponding name of id from TABLE2

```
OUTPUT
city    district    state   nation
c1      d1          s2      n1
c2      d1          s2      n1
c3      d2          s1      n2
```

Is it possible to write simple sql query to get the above output?

How??

Thanks

Comment: is state supposed to be s2 s2 s1?

Comment: yes. s2 s2 s1. sorry, my mistake

Answer (score 0):

```
select city.name as city
, district.name as distict
, state.name as state
, nation.name as nation
from table1 t1
inner join table2 city on city.id = t1.city
inner join table2 state on state.id = t1.state
inner join table2 district on district.id = t1.district
inner join table2 nation on nation.id = t1.nation
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    c.name as city, 
    d.name as district, 
    s.name as state, 
    n.name as nation 
FROM TABLE1 t1
JOIN TABLE2 c on t1.city=c.id
JOIN TABLE2 d on t1.district=d.id
JOIN TABLE2 s on t1.state=s.id
JOIN TABLE2 n on t1.nation=n.id;
```